# Connect to aerospike running in a vagrant vm on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, aerospike

I followed above steps to install aerospike on my Mac - https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/vagrant/mac/index.html
 I am able to open the AMC console on my system but I am unable to connect to aerospike via my Java aerospike client

I am creating my AerospikeClient like below in my Java code.

```
new AerospikeClient("172.28.128.3", 8081);
```

Getting below error. Can anyone let me know what the problem is.

```
Factory method 'aerospikeClient' threw exception; nested exception is com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException$Connection: Error Code 11: Failed to connect to host(s): 
172.28.128.3 8081 java.io.EOFException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try connecting to [port 3000](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/network/index.html), not 8081. That one is only open to allow AMC to connect from the macOS side to the cluster.

Install the [tools package](https://www.aerospike.com/download/tools/latest/) for macOS and try the following:

```
asinfo -h "172.28.128.3" -v version
```